# New Tag Request: "IIS-8.5"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We have a tags for "IIS", "IIS-7.5", and "IIS", but not for "IIS-8.5".

IIS 8.5 is included in Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: Tag created. Enjoy ;)